# How to extract elements in NSArray using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have an array (NSArray) with the following content:

```
  dates {
    dateOne =     {
            "date_one" = "2011-11-30";
            name = "test1";
            dateOne=true
    };
    dateTwo =     {
            "date_two" = "2011-11-30";
            name = "test2";
            dateTwo=false
    };
    dateThree =     {
            "date_Three" = "2011-11-30";
            dateTwo=true;
            name = "test3";
    };
```

the content above is being generating with the following line of code:

```
NSArray *dates = [myXmlParsed valueForKeyPath:@"myXml.dates"];
```

using NSLog:

```
NSLog(@"%@, '%@'", NSStringFromClass([dates class]), dates);
```

I get the following output:

```
__NSDictionaryM, '{
dateOne =     {
        "date_one" = "2011-11-30";
        name = "test1";
        dateOne=true
};
dateTwo =     {
        "date_two" = "2011-11-30";
        name = "test2";
        dateTwo=false
        name = "test3";
};
dateThree =     {
        "date_Three" = "2011-11-30";
        name = "test1";
        dateTwo=true;
        name = "test3";
};
}'
```

but I'm having problems getting the values of dictionaries inside of the array. My question is how can get the data of dateThree and how can I access to individual node of information for example date_Three ?

I'll really appreciate your help guys

Comment: Array? It looks like a dictionary of dictionaries. Where does it come from and why do you think it's an array?

Comment: I have add it the information to the description. I'm generating the array with the following line of code      NSArray *dates = [myXmlParsed valueForKeyPath:@"myXml.dates"];

Comment: The above is neither an array, nor a dictionary, neither in code nor JSON nor anything else. It has an unclosed initial bracket and semicolons instead of commas. Why don't you just use `NSLog` and ost that output?

Comment: the above content is the nslog output.

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%@, '%@'", NSStringFromClass([dates class]), dates);` give? Copy it exactly please.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out. I was using nsarray when I should have done nsmutabledictionary.

NSMutableDictionary *dates=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: [resultDict valueForKeyPath:@"myXml.dates"]];

Now I can query any of the values:

NSLog(@"value %@", [[dates valueForKey:@"dateOne"] valueForKey:@"date_one"]);